# Start turned based mobile game with server and then communication between mobile to mobile Dirctly (with no server)

Tags: php, android, ios, linux, apache

Is it possible and reliable to have functionality like
Start a turn based game with server just to have common meeting point, and once game is started between two mobile devices. instead of Mobile1 -> Server -> Mobile2 communicate directly to Mobile1 -> Mobile2

Desired Server configuration - > LAMP

Mobile Device -> iOS and Android

Thanks

Comment: How would you then control what they communicate? How you want to save game states and stuff?

Comment: I very much doubt it, the clients/phones would need a server & client implementation & if it was possible to listen on the given WAN ip, then what happens when someone connects via wifi behind an unconfigured NAT.

Comment: can it be saved locally on the moblie devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. This is how most P2P apps work. [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) will prevent direct connection between mobile devices, but by employing some form of [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) you could make it work.